# Copying an XML document with Xslt without any changes to the XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to copying an XML into an identical XML

I am using the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the Input XML is:

```
<CatalogRequest>
    <RequestFileHeader>
      <ClientCode>340000</ClientCode>
      <CreateTime>2012-04-11T14:57:03.357</CreateTime>
    </RequestFileHeader>
</CatalogRequest>
```

I get the following as result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<ROOT>
<CatalogRequest>
    <RequestFileHeader>
      <ClientCode>340000</ClientCode>
      <CreateTime>2012-04-11T14:57:03.357</CreateTime>
    </RequestFileHeader>
</CatalogRequest>
</ROOT>
```

Any idea on how to keep the same XML without the `<ROOT>` node added to it.

This is being called as follows:

```
Dim Xct As New XslCompiledTransform 
Xct.Load(New XmlTextReader(New StreamReader(xsltFileName))) 
Dim xal As New XsltArgumentList 
Dim helper As New XsltHelper 
xal.AddExtensionObject("urn:XsltHelper", helper) 
Dim memStream As New MemoryStream 
Dim streamWriter As New StreamWriter(memStream, Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))
Xct.Transform(doc, xal, streamWriter)
```

Comment: What processor are you using? I don't see how `ROOT` would be added by that XSLT.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, this is the first time I word with XSLT how do I know which processor I am using?

Comment: What code are you using to call the XSLT?

Comment: When adding information such as the calling code, please edit the post and add it to the body instead of adding a comment.  I've copied it there for you.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know

Comment: Apparently, the transformation depends on the XsltHelper class. Can you find out what's in there? You could try running without adding XsltHelper as extension to the XsltArgumentList. And check what the contents of doc are: maybe that is the ROOT element enclosing the input xml?

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that your calling code is automatically wrapping the XML you supply with a ROOT node.

I meant you to add this to your existing XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="ROOT">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Giving you this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="ROOT">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not promising this will work - it's a guess

Comment: I believe you are correct. But the XSLT you provided copies the value of the nodes (and not the nodes structure) and it creates an invalid XML. Any ideas?